# How can a Haskell compiler deal with small changes to large projects without a full recompile?

Tags: haskell

I'm huge Haskell n00b trying to learn more about it. I'm wondering given that Haskell is a lazily evaluated language it probably needs to analyze all the possible flows of a function call. Given that, if a transitive dependency of any function call changes then it wouldn't it require recompilation of that function? If so small changes could cascade to require a full recompile. How is this dealt with?

Comment: If a function is modified, then it'll need to be recompiled.  Anything that depends on that function or module will need to be recompiled.  This is not specific to Haskell, but rather how most modern compilers work.  If I'm writing C, Java, C#, or really anything else, changing a function can cascade into a large recompilation, but build systems have been made to automatically determine what needs to be recompiled (see: make, shake).

Comment: C, Java and C# have compilation units. If the function changed and its signature didn't only a a single file(compilation unit) needs to be recompiled. If a function signature changed then then only direct dependencies need to be recompiled but not transitive dependencies.

Comment: At least in GHC, if the function is small the compiler can choose to inline it, even in calls outside the current file. This is done by copying its code into the interface .hi file along with its type signature. The price for this is that, if the exported interface changes, i.e. if either the code or type change, then the direct dependencies need to be recompiled. If because of this the dependencies have now a different interface (e.g. nested inlining), then the recompilation is extended further. ghc --make and cabal recurse correctly as needed.

Comment: How is this "too broad"? This is perfectly answerable.

Comment: @alternative — "There are either too many possible answers, **or good answers would be too long for this format**."

Answer (score 2):

(I'm answering this as CW because I'm no expert, and I hope a proper answer will show up.)

There is a lot of information [on the GHC wiki about how GHC handles this problem](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/RecompilationAvoidance).

Your note about "analyze all the possible flows of a function call" is a bit off target--it's better to think of most of that evaluation as happening in the runtime system, not at compilation time. The bigger concern is that most significant programs are utterly dependent on GHC's aggressive optimizations, in particular pervasive inlining. The use of inlining implies recompilation of all call sites when a value is recompiled.

GHC is also, I think for similar reasons, considerably more conservative about "compilation units" than other languages. In particular, a value's type signature does *not* encapsulate its interface the way it might in other languages' dispatch or linking systems. For example, among other things GHC [records in a module's interface file](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/IfaceFiles) "[t]he strictness, arity, and unfolding of exported functions. This is crucial for cross-module optimisation; but it is only included when you compile with -O." (For a little on this sense of arity, see [this page](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/IfaceFiles) and the [paper on GHC function calls](http://www.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/eval-apply.pdf) linked there.) None of these features are part of a function's *type*, but have major implications for how downstream modules may be compiled.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you with _"In particular, a value's type signature does not encapsulate its interface the way it might in other languages' dispatch or linking systems."_. Could you explain the interface encapsulation difference you're talking about?